# how to print to a file in a recursive functions without losing previous contents?

Tags: shell, recursion, printing

I have a recursive function that has 2 recursive calls inside it (to itself) and I want to print the result for all the recursive calls without exiting the function. if the function calls for itself 10 times, I want to print the 10 results...
how can I do it?
(Its all in bash (shell on windows))
I tryed:

```
{
    echo function $1 > file
}
```

but it puts only the last result into `file`.

Comment: What don't you get by using echo?

Comment: echo gives me only the result of the last call

Comment: Have you tried append(`>>`) instead of overwrite(`>`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append to instead of overwrite `file`. The I/O redirection operator `>` truncates a file before writing, while the `>>` operator appends at the end of `file`.

Of course you should truncate `file` before the initial call to your function, otherwise it will keep appending with each call and `file` will grow. You can do so with the null command `:` and a redirection:

```
 : > file             # Create empty file or truncate nonempty file.
 recursive_function   # Appends to file.
 cat file             # Show result.
```